# Giving null reference when accessing Object using ODM for ldap in spring

Tags: spring, object, ldap, mapping

Need your help. I am getting null ref when mapping java object as user which contain properties.

```
@Entry(objectClasses =  {"person","top"} )
public final class  Users{


    @Id
    private Name dn;

    @Attribute(name="givenName")
    private String firstName;

    @Attribute(name="uid")
    private String uid;


    public String getUid() {
        return uid;
    }
    public void setUid(String uid) {
        this.uid = uid;
    }
    @Attribute(name="sn")
    private String lastName;

    @Attribute(name="cn")
    private  String fullName;
```

and calling it into main method:

```
public class Test {

    private static final SearchControls searchControls = 
            new SearchControls(SearchControls.SUBTREE_SCOPE, 0, 10000,
                null, true, false);

        private static final DistinguishedName baseDn = new DistinguishedName("ou=sa,o=data");

        private static void print(List<Users> personList) {
            for (Users person : personList) {
                System.out.println(person);
            }
        }

        public static void main(String[] argv) {
            ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(new String[] { "LdapContextSource.xml" });

            OdmManager odmManager = (OdmManager)context.getBean("odmManager");
            Users user=new Users();

            List<Users> searchResults = odmManager.findAll(Users.class,baseDn, searchControls);
            System.out.println(searchResults.get(0));

        }

}
```

and here is the my springcontext file;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>


<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-2.5.xsd">

    <bean id="fromStringConverter" class="org.springframework.ldap.odm.typeconversion.impl.converters.FromStringConverter" />
    <bean id="toStringConverter" class="org.springframework.ldap.odm.typeconversion.impl.converters.ToStringConverter" />

    <bean id="converterManager" class="org.springframework.ldap.odm.typeconversion.impl.ConverterManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="converterConfig">
            <set>
                <bean class="org.springframework.ldap.odm.typeconversion.impl.ConverterManagerFactoryBean$ConverterConfig">
                    <property name="fromClasses">
                         <set> 
                             <value>java.lang.String</value>
                         </set>
                     </property>
                     <property name="toClasses">
                         <set>
                             <value>java.lang.Byte</value>
                             <value>java.lang.Short</value>
                             <value>java.lang.Integer</value>
                             <value>java.lang.Long</value>
                             <value>java.lang.Float</value>
                             <value>java.lang.Double</value>
                             <value>java.lang.Boolean</value>
                         </set>
                    </property>
                    <property name="converter" ref="fromStringConverter" />
                </bean>
                <bean class="org.springframework.ldap.odm.typeconversion.impl.ConverterManagerFactoryBean$ConverterConfig">
                    <property name="fromClasses">
                        <set>
                             <value>java.lang.Byte</value>
                             <value>java.lang.Short</value>
                             <value>java.lang.Integer</value>
                             <value>java.lang.Long</value>
                             <value>java.lang.Float</value>
                             <value>java.lang.Double</value>
                             <value>java.lang.Boolean</value>
                         </set> 
                     </property>
                     <property name="toClasses">
                         <set> 
                             <value>java.lang.String</value>
                         </set>
                    </property>
                    <property name="converter" ref="toStringConverter" />
                </bean>
            </set>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="contextSourceTarget" class="org.springframework.ldap.core.support.LdapContextSource">
         <property name="url" value="ldap://172.16.9.27" />
    <!-- <property name="base" value="o=data" /> -->
    <property name="userDn" value="cn=adminua,ou=sa,o=data" />
    <property name="password" value="12345" />
    <property name="pooled" value="false" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="dirContextValidator" class="org.springframework.ldap.pool.validation.DefaultDirContextValidator">
        <property name="base" value="" />
        <property name="filter" value="objectclass=person" />
        <property name="searchControls.searchScope">
            <util:constant static-field="javax.naming.directory.SearchControls.OBJECT_SCOPE" />
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="contextSource" class="org.springframework.ldap.pool.factory.PoolingContextSource">
        <property name="contextSource" ref="contextSourceTarget" />
        <property name="dirContextValidator" ref="dirContextValidator" />
        <property name="maxActive" value="10" />
        <property name="maxTotal" value="10" />
        <property name="maxIdle" value="5" />
        <property name="minIdle" value="1" />
        <property name="timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis" value="60000" />
        <property name="testOnBorrow" value="true" />
        <property name="testWhileIdle" value="true" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="odmManager" class="org.springframework.ldap.odm.core.impl.OdmManagerImplFactoryBean">
        <property name="converterManager" ref="converterManager" />
        <property name="contextSource" ref="contextSource" />
        <property name="managedClasses">
            <set>
                <value>test.idm.core.entity.Users</value>
            </set>
        </property>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Please suggest me where is the mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Vinod,

You have to add "inetOrgPerson" object class to get results.

e.g.

@Entry(objectClasses = { "person","inetOrgPerson"})

I hope this will work for you.

BR

SD

Answer (score 0):

Entry's objectClasses should totally match objectClasses in LDAP, so if your ldap user has 
objectClass = person, objectClass = inetOrgPerson and objectClass = top, then all this values should be added to Entry annotation. Yoa can find relevant code into OdmManagerImpl.java line 446.